# jQuery Mobile+PhoneGap listViews: issue with list view attributes Auto-Divider and Img Source not working properly

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented an iPhone app using jQuery Mobile and Phone-Gap.

I need two requirements:

**1. Set the deviders in alphabetical order ( used auto-dividers)**
 [image]

**2. Add an image view to the left side of the row (used img src="egg.jpg")**

[image]

**1. Auto Deviders:-**

*`I used list-divides A,F,J,R for this table image`* *it fine for* **small amount of data** ***`but for large amount of data we need to use`***  **auto-dividers**.

So, **I have used AutoDividers** as the best option to set the deviders as follows **but it doesn't works**.

*i have get the above format shown in diagram using listodividers*

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" class="ui-listview">
      <li><a href="astra.html">Astra</a></li>
      <li><a href="zappa.html">Frank Zappa</a></li>
      <li><a href="tull.html">Jethro Tull</a></li>
      <li><a href="radiohead.html">Radiohead</a></li>
      <li><a href="who.html">The Who</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**2. Imgae Src**

I have used ***`<img src="egg.jpg"/>`*** as the best option to set the images as follows **but it doesn't works.**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" class="ui-listview">
                        <li><img src="egg.jpg"/> 
                            <a href="#egg" data-panel="main">Egg......</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="egg.jpg"/>  
                            <a href="#egg" data-panel="main">Egg......</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="egg.jpg"  class="ui-li-icom"/>  
                            <a href="#egg" data-panel="main">Egg......</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="album-bb.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
                            <a href="#egg" data-panel="main">Egg......</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Images are displayed on the text or above the cell for different formats as mentioned above in list items

**`Why these are not working for properly my app......?`**

I used **xcode 4.1**

**Cordova 1.7.0** for phoneGap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like this

```
<li>
     <a href="#egg" data-panel="main">
         <img src="egg.jpg"/>  
         <p>Egg......</p>
     </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Hey fend is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is anything to do with PhoneGap. I would recommend browsing your pages in a browser such as Chrome or Firefox and use the developer tools to check your CSS. If it works there then try it in the app.

Comment: Did you try with the browser window resized to the size of a phone? Try the Window Resizer extension for Chrome.